# How to trace which user has sent FCM notification?

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I have integrated with FCM. I have sent notifications to my apps.

I have added multiple users to my Firebase account.

How can I know which of these user has sent given notification?

I tried GCP Logger but it is not listing anything related to Cloud Messaging

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to know which user called the FCM API to send messages that I know of. If you need this, you'll have to implement it in your application code, for example by logging it yourself each time you call the FCM API.

Comment: Does this also applies push notifications sent via to Firebase Console?

Comment: Hmm.... I'm not sure. I don't know of any way to log who sends notifications from the Firebase console, but that doesn't mean it doesn't exist. If this is indeed what you're looking for, I recommend clarifying in your question as most people will likely interpret it was I did (since the vast majority of FCM messages gets sent through the REST API).

Comment: Thanks. I received reply from Firebase support. They informed me that I have to implement this requirement my self while when consuming REST API. Firebase console does not record which user has sent which notification.